# Is typecasting long to size_t safe?

Tags: c, file, casting, io

I want to use `ftell` to get the current position of stream, but I want to be able to typecast it to a `size_t`, which would be an unsigned instead. signed and unsigned are different because one is signed and the other is unsigned.

The return type of `ftell` is `long`, and that's different than `size_t`.

So, in this situation when using `ftell`, is it safe to use `size_t` for it instead of `long`?

```c
char *s = malloc(ftell(whateverstream));
```

I'm going to be using `ftell` for dynamic memory allocation, so I was wondering if it's safe to use long instead of size_t.

Comment: `ftell` can return a negative value, so that line of code is **not** safe.

Comment: You should always check the return value first, it’ll be negative if an error occurred. Then you know it’s positive and can use it

Comment: In general yes it is safe (after validating the return is non-negative), while `size_t` and `long` should generally have the same rank, an implementation can choose to do something differently [C11 Standard - 7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p4)

Comment: How do you know `size_t` “which would be an unsigned long instead”? If you know that because it is specific to the C implementation(s) you are using, then casting a non-negative `long` value to `size_t` is safe. If you “know” it because you think that is how C works, it is not safe. The C standard permits `size_t` to be narrower than `long`, and files on disk can be larger than the memory address space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right. Instead of saying `unsigned long`, I just should know that it's `unsigned` and not `signed`. Thank you for acknowledging.

Comment: `char *s = malloc(ftell(whateverstream));` is going to cause problems if [the stream is in text mode](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "safe" -- it is always well-defined to convert a long to a size_t, but that might not do what you want.

The basic problem is that there's no mandated relationship between long and size_t -- a size_t might be smaller than a long, or larger, or the same size.  It depends on the implementation (machine and compiler).

If you're using a POSIX system, there's also `ftello`, which returns an `off_t` rather than a long (which might be larger than a long, and larger or smaller than a size_t).

So to be totally safe, you need to check all the possible combinations -- check that the return value from ftell(o) is not negative, and then after converting it to a size_t, check that it didn't wrap due to overflow

```
long off = ftell(whatever);
size_t size = (size_t)off;
if (off < 0) {
    /* there was an error determining the size of the stream */
} else if (size != off) {
    /* overflow converting to size -- stream is too big */
} else {
    /* converted successfully */
}
```

Comment: If there's an overflow, would anything bad happen to the program?

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, so overflow is well-defined -- the value wraps modulo the size of the type.